# Importing a `bson` dataset with montorestore

Tags: database, mongodb, mongorestore

I have created a database, `Restuarants` through Atlas and made an empty collection, `restuarants`.

I connected to my Atlas account with mongosh and attempted to import a `.bson` file with `restore` using the following command:

`mongorestore -d Restaurants -c restaurants /Users/username/restaurants.sampleRestaurants.bson`

However, I get the following error:

> Uncaught:
> TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'message' of object 'SyntaxError: unknown: Missing semicolon. (1:15)

I can't tell what's wrong. Been looking through the docs but can't really find an answer.